# BreezeJs - Ajax Calls with Parameters, No Caching

Tags: javascript, ajax, caching, breeze

BreezeJs' POST Ajax calls with parameters that I make to retrieve data are cached by the browser. The `"cache: false"` attribute does not work, neither does the `$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });` option. How do I prevent it from happening? And if, I need to make GET requests instead, how do I procede? Here is a portion of my code...

JS

```
var id = 100;
var serviceName = '/breeze/sample';
var ajaxImpl = breeze.config.getAdapterInstance('ajax');

ajaxImpl.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: serviceName + '/getdata',
    data: { dataid: id },
    success: function(data) {
        // Do something with data
    }
});
```

ApiController

```
[HttpPost]
[Authorize("User")]
[ActionName("getdata")]
public object GetData(HttpRequestMessage request)
{
    if (!IsAuthorized()) // Pre-defined function
        throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);

    var data = request.Content.ReadAsFormDataAsync().Result;
    var dataId = data["dataid"];
    var query = "sp_getdata @id"; // Pass parameter @id to stored procedure "sp_getdata"
    var id = new SqlParameter("@id", dataId);

    return unitOfWork.Context().ExecuteStoreQuery<GetData>(query, id).ToList();
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

We run breeze with GET and POST.

Do you have a Global.asax? Add this to it... not sure if looking for /api/ or /breeze/ would be the only way, but adjust to your circumstances.

```
protected void Application_PreSendRequestHeaders(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Never Cache API (Web API or Breeze.Sharp) Data Requests
    if (Request.RawUrl.Contains("/api/") || Request.RawUrl.Contains("/breeze/"))
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. Quick question... Under Google Chrome's Developer Tools | Network, what does "[amount of data] transferred" actually mean? I've always thought that it represents amount of data stored in the cache...

Comment: I think that represents the size of the request in bytes.